# Applying fitting data with nls

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

Hi and thank you in advance for any suggestions here! My question is using `nls()` how can I

1. find the best optimal fit amongst the other fits-- ie linear and non linear-- for my data and
2. show the fit on the ggplot graph below?

   ```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(mosiac)
   library(tidyverse)
   library(dplyr)

   # data frame
   FX <- data.frame(Location=c(1:5), mi=c(1, 4, 16, 16^2,256^2))

   #Visual
   ggplot(FX,aes(x=Location, y=mi))+
     geom_line(alpha=0.9, color="red")

   # nls(). It shows error of Error in nls(mi ~ Location, data = FX, start = list(mi = 1, 
   #Location = 1)) : 
   #no parameters to fit
   nls(mi~Location,data=FX,start=list(mi=1,Location=1))
   ```

Comment: It is unclear what you intend to achieve with your last line of code.

Comment: You might want to fit log(mi) to a function of Location.  This seems to work: `nls(log(mi) ~ a * Location / (1 + b * Location), FX, start = list(a = 1, b = 1))`

Comment: @ Roland,  to obtain the coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include adjustable parameters for your equation in the `nls()` function.

```
FX <- data.frame(Location=c(1:5), mi=c(1, 4, 16, 16^2,256^2))

nls(mi~a+Location^b, data=FX, start=list(a=1, b=4))

# Nonlinear regression model
# model: mi ~ a + Location^b
# data: FX
# a         b 
# -3573.540     6.906 
# residual sum-of-squares: 142513083
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 8 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.011e-06
```

Comment: Hello Dave2e, great. This answers the first part of my question. I do not understand however, how you got your `model: mi ~ a + Location^b`?

Comment: You need to define an equation for `nls()` to fit.  Since I had no prior knowledge of what this data is suppose to respresent, I randomly chose the exponential a*x^b.  You may have other expectations and need create another equation that would better suit your data.

Comment: Thank you, Dave2e. Just to be clear you chose arbitrary coefficient values for a and b?

Comment: Yes, the model and the starting values for a & b were arbitrary.

Comment: Would it be suggested that I post my second question  in this post as a new post?

Comment: It would be best to post a new question.